# How to make Maven build fail on warnings?

Tags: maven, warnings

Sometimes my Maven build gives a warning, i.e., the Maven output has a line starting with `[WARNING]`.  (I am not talking about, e.g., warnings in compiled Java code, but, e.g., a warning that an empty jar-file is being created.)

In such a situation I want my build to fail.  How do I do that?

Comment: I doubt it's possible to do this by means of maven only. In each of the plugins that are involved in your project build process you'd have to find some setting to fail build in case warning has been issued and I don't recall any such plugin (apart from compiler, maybe).

Comment: Suggested to Maven team: [MNG-5091](http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/MNG-5091)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This feature was already suggested to Maven team in [MNG-5091](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MNG-5091). Upvote it in their JIRA and let's wait (this is what I did) :)

Comment: Please note that the referenced MNG-5091 contains what seems to be a workaround, which makes this possible with the current version of Maven.  But I have not tried that yet.

Comment: Well, today i discovered the GMaven plugin - interesting. FYI the workaround as provided fails with: `java.lang.reflect.InaccessibleObjectException: Unable to make protected void java.lang.Object.finalize() throws java.lang.Throwable accessible: module java.base does not "opens java.lang" to unnamed module @bf75b5c` on Java 18.