# how to get mvn install fail if there are warnings on pom validation?

Tags: java, maven, jenkins, lint

I launch a maven build (from local env or from jenkins) that has some warning, for example:

```
[WARNING] Some problems were encountered while building the effective model for com.example:application:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT
[WARNING] some random warning @ com.example:application:${project.version}, /var/jenkins_home/workspace/com-example/example/pom.xml, line 14, column 11
```

is there a way to let the mvn build fail if there are this kind of warning?

Let me clarify:

I don't need a solution to the specific argument (the project.version variable)

I need that when i run

```
mvn install
```

and I get a "[WARNING] ...somethingsomething"

the mvn build fails and i got a 1 as a return code of the process:

```
mvn install
...
[WARNING]...
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
```

Comment: unfortunately that's not the case. i've got not java compilation errors. i've got malformed poms. for example: dependencies without versions, variables used where they are not allowed, etc

Comment: i updated the first post to add a more explicit warning

Comment: The problem is that you are using an expression for a version like `<version>${version}</version>` instead a literal value or if you are using [ci friendly](https://maven.apache.org/maven-ci-friendly.html) you have to use a particular set of properties incl. flatten-maven-plugin. Otherwise this will result in non usable pom's for other who like to consume this. This is a big issue. You should fix that...

Comment: @khmarbaise i know what the specific problem was, I just need the build to fail if a problem like this shows up. I updated the post, trying to be more clear

Comment: This has been already asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14495014/13237531)

Comment: @Vladimir but doesnt respond to the question. in the meanwhile i found a viable solution. i'm updating the thread

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the solution was actually more easy than expected.
Just needed a little script to run the build. I'm omitting soem env vars.

Also, I found out that using the "pipe" | operator, I was hiding the result of the first command, and I found out that it's possible to get the result of a specific pipe stage using PIPESTATUS env var

```
./mvnw $MVN_CLI_OPTS -f $1 $2 | tee build.log
if [[ "${PIPESTATUS[0]}" == "1" ]]; then
    echo "mvn build failed"
    return 1
fi
#this will grep only in the first n rows of the log
head -n30 build.log | grep -in "\[WARNING\]"
if [[ ! -z "$FAIL_ON_WARNING" && $? == 0 ]]; then
    echo "--------------------------------------"
    echo "PLEASE FIX MAVEN BUILD WARNINGS AND RETRY"
    echo "BUILD STATUS: FAILED"
    echo "--------------------------------------"
    return 1
fi
```